# Disabling weak cipher suites in Tomcat does not work as expected

Tags: tls, java, cipher-selection, tomcat

I have to get rid of so called "weak security" in a Tomcat application.
A penetration test identified services that accept connections with insecure TLS encryption and hashing algorithms: TLS 1.0/1.1,SHA1,CBC

Without being a Tomcat developer I found out that cipher suites and TLS version are set in conf/server.xml:

This is how it looks like right now - note the list of ciphers which shall be supported:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8006" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener"/>
    <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
    <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
    <Listener SSLEngine="on" className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"/>
    <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>
    <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
    <GlobalNamingResources>
        <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
        <Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
    </GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
    <Service name="Catalina">
        <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
        <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->
        <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
        <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8181" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8444" server="-"/>
        <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
        <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
        <!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the NIO implementation. The default
         SSLImplementation will depend on the presence of the APR/native
         library and the useOpenSSL attribute of the
         AprLifecycleListener.
         Either JSSE or OpenSSL style configuration may be used regardless of
         the SSLImplementation selected. JSSE style configuration is used below.
    -->
        <!-- HTTPS -->
        <Connector 
        SSLEnabled="true" 
        connectionTimeout="60000" 
        maxKeepAliveRequests="250" 
        maxThreads="300" port="8081" 
        protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
        >
        <!-- 
        The cipher suites below are secure ciphers from https://ciphersuite.info/cs/
        TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3 is enabled, so TLSv1.1 is disabled, as well as SSL
        -->
            <SSLHostConfig

        sslProtocol="TLSv1.2" 
        sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3"
        ciphers="
            TLS_PSK_DHE_WITH_AES_256_CCM_8,
            TLS_PSK_DHE_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8,
            TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256,
            TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_GCM_SHA384,
            TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_GCM_SHA256,
            TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_ARIA_256_GCM_SHA384,
            TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_ARIA_128_GCM_SHA256,
            TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
            TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
            TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256,
            TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
            TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
            TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CCM_SHA256,
            TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8_SHA256,
            TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256,
            TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_GCM_SHA384,
            TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_GCM_SHA256,
            TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_ARIA_256_GCM_SHA384,
            TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_ARIA_128_GCM_SHA256,
            TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
            TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM_8,
            TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM,
            TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
            TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8,
            TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM,
            TLS_ECCPWD_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
            TLS_ECCPWD_WITH_AES_256_CCM_SHA384,
            TLS_ECCPWD_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
            TLS_ECCPWD_WITH_AES_128_CCM_SHA256,
            TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256,
            TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_GCM_SHA384,
            TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_GCM_SHA256,
            TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_ARIA_256_GCM_SHA384,
            TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_ARIA_128_GCM_SHA256,
            TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
            TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM_8,
            TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM,
            TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
            TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8,
            TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM,
            TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256,
            TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_GCM_SHA384,
            TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_GCM_SHA256,
            TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_ARIA_256_GCM_SHA384,
            TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_ARIA_128_GCM_SHA256,
            TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
            TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CCM,
            TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
            TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CCM,
            TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_GCM_SHA384,
            TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_GCM_SHA256,
            TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_ARIA_256_GCM_SHA384,
            TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_ARIA_128_GCM_SHA256,
            TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
            TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
            TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256,
            TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
            TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
            TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256,
            TLS_AES_128_CCM_8_SHA256">
                <Certificate 
                certificateKeyAlias="xxxxx" 
                certificateKeystoreFile="/home/xxxxx/keystore" 
                certificateKeystorePassword="xxxxx" 
                certificateKeystoreType="xxxx" 
                type="RSA"/>
            </SSLHostConfig>
        </Connector>
        <Connector port="9010" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8444"/>
        <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->
        <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
        <Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">
            <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
            <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->
            <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
                <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
                <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase">
                    <CredentialHandler algorithm="SHA" className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler"/>
                    <CredentialHandler algorithm="SHA" className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler"/>
                    <CredentialHandler algorithm="SHA" className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler"/>
                </Realm>
            </Realm>
            <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
                <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
                <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->
                <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
                <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"/>
            </Host>
        </Engine>
    </Service>
</Server>
```

However, when I test the service on port 8081 with SoapUI, it seems that a cipher is to be used which is not in the list:
[image]

What am I doing wrong here - I expected that only ciphers from the list can be used.

Comment: Despite the question is about security, it does not make it automatically relevant to Security SE. This is a pure software configuration question and is off-topic on this site. I'd suggest you to start with Tomcat [SSL/TLS Configuration How-To](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.1-doc/ssl-howto.html#SSL_and_Tomcat).

Comment: This hint helped a lot. Problem is solved now.